# Can't go out the while loop

Tags: python

```
a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0")
while a != 0 or 1:
    print"please retype"
    a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0")
print "thanks"
```

---

I don't know why my output always repeats line 3 and 4 no matter what figure I typed in.
Thank you

Comment: Condition in `while` always is `True`.

Comment: `while a != 0 or a !=1:` is needed. `1` is always true. Edit: actually a cant be both 1 and 0, so it's always either not 0 or not 1, so what you're looking for is probably `while a!=0 and a!=1`

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, you need to cast to `int`

Comment: You could try `while a not in (0, 1):`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: 2nd part of dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a != 0 or 1` is actually interpreted as `(a != 0) or (1)`, where the expressions enclosed in parentheses are evaluated as booleans. Since `1` is always `True`, the `while` loop continues to run forever, irrespective of the value of `a`.

See the near-duplicate [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) for more information on why the `or` operator does not serve the purpose you might expect in this situation.

You should use strings in your condition, since `raw_input` returns a string, and check whether `a` is one of several possibilities using the `not in` operator and a tuple:

```
a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0")
while a not in ('1', '0'):
    print("please retype")
    a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0")
print("thanks")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another example:

```
a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0\n")
while True:
    if a in ("1", "0"):
        break
    print "please retype"
    a = raw_input("please type 1 or 0\n")
print "thanks"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper variable to determine if the criteria are met.

```
b = True
while b:
    a = input("please type 1 or 0")
    if a == "0" or a == "1":
        b = False
    else:
        print("please retype")

print("thanks")
```

This also prevents non integer characters from throwing an error.